# Is CLOCK_THREAD_CPUTIME_ID the same as pthread_getcpuclockid(pthread_self(),..)?

Tags: cpu-time

In terms of obtaining per-thread CPU time using Posix clock_gettime(): is there any difference between using the clock ID obtained from pthread_getcpuclockid(pthread_self(),..) or using CLOCK_THREAD_CPUTIME_ID?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per the [man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_getcpuclockid.3.html):

```
NOTES

   When thread refers to the calling thread, this function returns an
   identifier that refers to the same clock manipulated by
   clock_gettime(2) and clock_settime(2) when given the clock ID
   CLOCK_THREAD_CPUTIME_ID.
```

Comment: Thanks, that satisifies me as the OS is indeed linux.  The question was prompted because I was looking at the POSIX man pages (http://pubs.opengroup.org) but didn't find any such note.  I wonder if the same is true of all POSIX OS?